# Constructor of object as function parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, binding

I have a function that takes a reference to an object and duplicates it using an user-defined function. I would like to give the copy constructor of the object as default value of this function. Is it possible?

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo(T const & obj, std::function<T(T const &)> const & copy){
    std::vector<T> iv;
    size_t n=5;
    for(size_t i=0U; i!=n; ++i){
        iv.emplace_back(copy(obj));
    }
    //do stuff with iv
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't obtain a reference to the copy constructor (or any constructor for that matter), but you can wrap the object creation which calls the c'tor in a lambda:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T const & obj, std::function<T(T const &)> const & copy = [](T const& t){ return T(t); }){
    std::vector<T> iv;
    size_t n=5;
    for(size_t i=0U; i!=n; ++i){
        iv.emplace_back(copy(obj));
    }
    //do stuff with iv
    return;
}
```

The return value optimization will however make it behave as though you could obtain a reference to the copy c'tor and call it, without too many copies along the way.

You can also get rid of another copy by a further layer of indirection. Since `emplace_back` takes an argument by reference, the value `copy` returns needs to be materialized early, and copied again inside the implementation of `emplace_back`. If you were to pass instead another object, one convertible to a `T`, you could spare another copy. I can be done as follows

```
template<class T>
void foo(T const & obj, std::function<T(T const &)> const & copy = [](T const& t){ return T(t); }){

    struct {
        T const& obj;
        std::function<T(T const &)> const & copy;
        operator T() {
            return copy(obj);
        }
    } obtainer{obj, copy};

    std::vector<T> iv;
    size_t n=5;
    for(size_t i=0U; i!=n; ++i){
        iv.emplace_back(obtainer);
    }
    //do stuff with iv
    return;
}
```

A reference to the `obtainer` object is passed into the innards of `emplace_back`, and when it's time to create the new object, the conversion function kicks in. We can expect RVO to eliminate all the copies now, and construct the new value in place with the help of the copy c'tor.